# how get and compare two mysql data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**table 1**

> two column >> paid - order_num1

**table 2**

> two column >> order_num2

I want get `order_num2` value from `table 2` and

```
update paid(insert paid = 1) in table one with same order_num value
```

If `order_num1=order_num2` then `paid = 1` in **table 1**

```
$q = mysql_query("select order_num2 from table2 where samevalue = samevalue ");
$x = mysql_fetch_row($q);
mysql_query("update table1 set paid=1 where order_num1='$x['order_num2']'");
```

But it does not work!
First get from one table and update paid from another table if `order_num` have same value

Comment: I tried, but I think its not clear enough to help you

Comment: where table1.column = table2.column ?

Comment: please clarify your problem, i can't understand

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$table2 = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table2");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($table2);
$num2 = $row['order_num2'];

$table1 = mysqli_query("SELECT * from table1");
$roww = mysqli_fetch_array($table1);
$num1 = $row['order_num1'];

if ($num2 == $num1) {
$updateDB = mysqli_query("UPDATE table1 SET paid = 1 WHERE order_num1 = '$num2'");
} else {
//Not equal so the paid column wont get updated
}
```